# Angular 4 ng-selected not working

Tags: html, angular

I cannot get `ng-selected` to work. I first tried just adding `selected` in the option tag, but after reading it seems like I need to use `ng-select`. I've tried doing `ng-selected="true"` and `ng-selected="selected"` with no luck. I've tried doing the recommended fixes from other stackeoverflow questions but none seem to work for me. At one point (in another html form bc I am having this same problem) it seemed to work, but now it magically stopped.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Caloric Intake Recommendation</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="weight" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Weight</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                id="weight"
                formControlName="weight"
                placeholder="Weight">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="goal" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Goal</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="goal" id="goal">
              <option ng-selected="selected">Lose Weight</option>
              <option>Maintain Weight</option>
              <option>Gain Mass</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit
        </button>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Your Recommended Protein:</label>
          <input type="text" value={{this.protein}}>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Your Recommended Carbs:</label>
          <input type="text" value={{this.carbs}}>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Your Recommended Fats:</label>
          <input type="text" value={{this.fat}}>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Component

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {CaloricIntakeClass} from "./caloric-intake.class";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-caloric-intake',
  templateUrl: './caloric-intake.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./caloric-intake.component.css']
})
export class CaloricIntakeComponent{
  myForm: FormGroup;
  caloricIntake: CaloricIntakeClass;
  weight: number;
  goal: string;
  protein: number;
  carbs: number;
  fat: number;


  onSubmit() {
    this.weight = this.myForm.value.weight;
    this.goal = this.myForm.value.goal;
    this.myForm.reset();

    this.caloricIntake = new CaloricIntakeClass(this.weight);
    if (this.goal === 'Cutting'){
          this.caloricIntake.cuttingIntake();
    } else if (this.goal === 'Bulking'){
          this.caloricIntake.bulkingIntake();
    } else {
          this.caloricIntake.maintaingIntake();
    }
    this.protein = this.caloricIntake.getProtein();
    this.carbs = this.caloricIntake.getCarbs();
    this.fat = this.caloricIntake.getFat();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      weight: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      goal: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Since ng-selected sets the 'selected' variable if the enclosed expression returns true, the question then becomes whether you have a variable named 'selected' and is set to true in your component. Can you show your component as well?

Comment: @DanielH.J. yup it is added now!

Comment: So I suppose you want to have "Lose Weight" selected by default?

Comment: @DanielH.J. yup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, your option's ng-selected is bound to a variable called 'selected'. That means in your component, you need to set this variable to true at the beginning, something like this:

```
export class CaloricIntakeComponent{

    selected : boolean;

    ......

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selected = true;
        ......

    }

}
```

### Update

Make sure you have values in the options, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="goal" id="goal">
    <option value="lose_weight">Lose Weight</option>
    <option value="maintain_weight">Maintain Weight</option>
    <option value="gain_mass">Gain Mass</option>
</select>
```

Then, you do not need ng-selected at all. You can just initiate with your custom values in the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        weight: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        goal: new FormControl("lose_weight", Validators.required)
    });
}
```

Comment: I can definitely see the logic here (and I did just try it), but the thing is, even when I do `ng-selected="true"` instead of what I currently have, it didn't work.

Comment: Could you try set the values in the options? Like <option value="lose_weight">Lose Weight</option>?

Comment: Oh, and also because you are initiating myForm, you are populating the select element with the value null. I will try update my answer.

Comment: What would setting the value do out of curiosity? I thought that was generally used for input fields (new to web development is why I ask)

Comment: Ah, good catch! That makes sense of to why it worked earlier and then stopped. Bc I added html first (it worked) and then when adding the angular part (FormControl) it stopped. Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you initialize FormGroup in ngOnInit, you are setting the rules of each form control. The first parameter is the default value, and the second is validator. Any form elements work the same because they all bind a value to a key in the form.

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)